# Why are Angular error messages (javascript console) formatted so weird?

Tags: angular

As I am slowly getting re-acquainted with Angular, I am working through basic samples. According to  the tutorial there should be a clean error message stating "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'." (I did not yet add the FormsModule to the imports.

Instead I get this mess:

[image: Unreadable error in javascript console]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

This is an error that was re-directed from the Angular CLI to the browser. It usually happens when there are compile-time errors and the application bundle couldn't build correctly. The strange symbols you're seeing (`\x18[96` etc.) are codes to make characters rendered in color in UNIX terminals - e.g. the red color for errors.

Runtime errors have proper stack traces and usually contain meaningful error messages like `"Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'."`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of a way to "fix" this - e.g. just ignore the color codes in the developer console?